# Attribute values show only after "Save"

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have an attribute `USD_Price`... It is visible in all products in magento admin panel. However, there are no values in the attribute (EMPTY). The only way for attribute values to be visible is to go into EACH product and click "SAVE". It's time consuming to go into each product and "save" it.

What could be done?

```
class Your_Module_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Usdprice extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract`
{
    /**
     * Before save method
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $basePrice = $object->getData('price');`

        $value = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($basePrice, Mage::app()->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode(), 'USD');
        $object->setData($attrCode, $value);

        return $this;
    }
}
```